# How to cut up two rounded rectangles into this

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, pathfinder

I want to recreate this in Illustrator.

[image: rounded rectangles]

I have created two rounded rectangles and used the Pathfinder pnael to cut them up. I now have this:

[image: my attempt]

But I still doesn't know how to make on arche endpoint come inwards to match the sequare edge and also how to add equal white-space (the cuts).

I'd appreciate some pointers.

Comment: Draw additional paths/shapes for the spaces. Use Shape Builder to remove areas.

Comment: To be honest i wouldnt use this spproach but yeah use shape builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a shape like this.

[image]

These are two rounded rectangles, with wide strokes, expanded to outlines, and four squares at the intersections.

Then use the Shape Builder tool to make the pieces. When you have finished add gradient fills to each piece.

[image]

Comment: Genius! Billy to the rescue again! Much appreciated.

Comment: You know you can *drag* with the Shape Builder tool, right?  If I had to click, click, click, click, click, click, it'd drive me crazy... not that I'm not already, but...

Comment: @Scott - Yeah LOL, but to keep the GIF screen capture small, I had to zoom out, making it almost impossible to click and drag accurately.  Much easier to do if you can zoom in a bit.

Comment: If you doubleclick on the tool you can change the drag to line which might be easier when capturing.